# I'm getting this error in Swift 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "save1D"; desired type = NSData; given type = Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray;

I've been stuck on this a few days now. I'm trying to save to and load from core data. I'm trying to save arrays from a collection view into a tableview then reload them back into a collection view. I've not been able to find a solution that fits what I need. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't se it. Can anyone help me with this?

```
 @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: Any) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextSave", in: context)
        let textEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        textEntity.setValue(v1, forKey: "save1D")
        textEntity.setValue(i1, forKey: "save2D")
        textEntity.setValue(ImageView, forKey: "picCock")

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved")

        } catch {
            print("failed save")
        }
        }
   func getData() {
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
             let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TextSave")
             request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

             do {
                 let result = try context.fetch(request)
                 for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]
                 {
                    v1 = data.value(forKey: "save1D") as! [String]
                    i1 = data.value(forKey: "save2D") as! [String]
                     ImageView = (data.value(forKey: "picCock") as! UIImageView)
                 }
             } catch {
                 print("failed")
             }
             }
```

Comment: Rather than KVC (`setValue`) use the `TextSave` subclass and dot notation. The benefit is you get a type mismatch error at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
textEntity.setValue(v1, forKey: "save1D")
```

`v1` is of type `NSData` while it should be an array

Comment: var v1 = [String]()
    var i1 = [String]()
The are already arrays, and the error is saying "reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "save1D"; desired type = NSData; given type = Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray;" it seems to be asking for NSData not an array.